# in jqgrid, is there anyway i can bring up the Multi columns filter GUI by clicking on a button outside of the grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

is there anyway to programatically launch the Advance multi select gui with a button click or some external event using jquery.  I want to add an icon at the top of the Gui to allow people to filter as people keep missing it in the status bar at the bottom of the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching)). The code is

```
var pSearch = {multipleSearch:true,overlay:false /* any parameters */}
$("#list").jqGrid("searchGrid",pSearch);
```

The code which will be executed by jqGrid if one click on the search button on the navigator is [the same](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.formedit.js#L1765).

Comment: i dont want to set or change any of the parameters.. i just want to bring up the GUI as if i clicked on the "find button" so it will populate with whatever the current filter is set to . .

Comment: @ooo: I don't understand where is the problem. Do you have no access to the `pSearch` parameters used in `navGrid`? You can use the same parameters for both functions. If you want to simulate click on the the "Search" button you can use $("#search_list").trigger('click') where "list" is the grid id.